# How to detect programmatically count of bytes allocated by process on Heap?

Tags: c++, linux

How to detect programmatically count of bytes allocated by process on Heap?
This test should work from process itself.

Comment: Why? If we know why then it may be easier to recommend something rather than throwing out the million and 1 (dangerious) techniques that exist.

Comment: I have memory leak , that can't be found by valgrind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A speculative solution: redefine `new` and `delete` operators.

On each `new` operator call, a number of bytes to allocate is passed.  Allocate a bit more memory and store the amount of bytes allocated within.  Add this amount to global variable that holds the heap size.

On `delete` operator call, check the value you stored before you dispose the memory.  Subtract it from that global variable.

Answer (score 9):

I think mallinfo() is what you want:

```
#include <malloc.h>


struct mallinfo *info;

info = mallinfo();

printf ("total allocated space:  %llu bytes\n", info->uordblks);
printf ("total free space:       %llu bytes\n", info->fordblks);
```

The struct mallinfo structure is technical, and specific to the malloc() implementation.  But the information you want is in there.  Here is how I report the values:

```
mallinfo.arena = "Total Size (bytes)" 
mallinfo.uordblks = "Busy size (bytes)" 
mallinfo.fordblks = "Free size (bytes)" 
mallinfo.ordblks = "Free blocks (count)" 
mallinfo.keepcost = "Top block size (bytes)" 
mallinfo.hblks = "Blocks mapped via mmap() (count)" 
mallinfo.hblkhd = "Bytes mapped via mmap() (bytes)"
```

These two are allegedly not used, but they seem to change on my system, and thus might be valid:

```
mallinfo.smblks = "Fast bin blocks (count)"
mallinfo.fsmblks = "Fast bin bytes (bytes)"
```

And the other interesting value is returned by "sbrk (0)"

Comment: Looks deprecated or not useful in 2017 for 64 bit machines, for memory allocated greater than 2 GB :(

Comment: The fact that mallinfo's fields are ints means, to me, that it should be avoided at all costs in new code.  Look at malloc_info() instead (unfortunately that function print xml for some god-forsaken reason).

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of possibilities.

How accurate do you need it to be?  You can get some useful data via **cat /proc/${PID}/status | grep VmData**.

You can **#define** your own **malloc()**, **realloc()**, **calloc()**, and **free()** functions, wrapping the real functions behind your own counter.  You can do really cool things here with __FILE__, __LINE__, & __func__ to facilitate identifying core leaks in simple tests.  ***But it will only instrument your own code!***

(Similarly, you can also redefine the default **operator new** and **operator delete** methods, both array and non-array variants, and both throwing std::bad_alloc and std::nothrow_t variants.  ***Again, this will only instrument your own code!)***

(Be aware:  On most C++ systems,  *new* ultimately invokes *malloc()*.  It doesn't have to.  Especially with in-place *new*!  But typically *new* does make use of *malloc()*.  (Or it operates on a region of memory that has previously been *malloc()'ed*.)  Otherwise you'd get into really funky stuff with multiple heap managers...)

You can use **sbrk(0)** to see where the data segment is currently set.  That's not so great.  It's a very coarse measurement, and it doesn't account for holes (unused memory regions) in the heap.  (You're much better off with the **VmData** line from **/proc/${PID}/status**.)  But if you're just looking for a general idea...

You can trap *malloc()/free()/etc* by writing your own shared library and forcing your process to use it instead of the real versions via **LD_PRELOAD**.  You can use **dlopen()/dlsym()** to load & invoke the *real* *malloc()/free()/etc*.  This works quite beautifully.  The original code is unmodified, not even recompiled.  But be aware of re-entrant situations when coding this library, and that your process will initially invoke *malloc()/calloc()/realloc()* before *dlopen()/dlsym()* can complete loading the real functions.

You might check out tools like **Valgrind**, though that's really aimed more at memory leaks.

---

Then again, perhaps **mtrace()** is what you want?  Or **__malloc_hook**?  Very proprietary (GNU) & nonstandard...  But you are tagged "Linux"...

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy, *automatic* way to do it, if that's what you're asking.  You basically have to manually keep track of heap allocations yourself using a counter variable.  The problem is that it's difficult to control which parts of your program are allocating memory on the heap, especially if you're using a lot of libraries out of your control.  To complicate things further, there's two ways a program might allocate heap memory: `new` or `malloc`.  (Not to mention direct OS calls like `sbrk`.)

You can [override global operator `new`](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=40), and have each call to new increase a global tally.  However, this won't necessarily include times when your program calls `malloc`, or when your program uses some class-specific `new` override.  You can also override `malloc` using a macro, but this is not necessarily portable.  And you'd also have to override all the variations of `malloc`, like `realloc`, `calloc`, etc.  All of this is further complicated by the fact that on some implementations, `new` itself may call `malloc`.

So, essentially, it's very difficult to do this properly from within your program.  I'd recommend using a memory profiler tool instead.

Comment: The hyperlink mentioned here, doesn't seem to point to the right resource.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on windows, you can use `GetProcessHeap()`, `HeapQueryInfo()` to retrieve information about the processes heap. [An example of walking the heap from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee175819%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged your question 'linux' it might help to look at some of the information provided in the `/proc` directory. I haven't researched this a lot so I can only give you a starting point.

`/proc/<your programs pid>` contains files with some information about your process from the viewpoint of the kernel. There is a symlink `/proc/self` that will always about the process your investigating this from.

The files you might be most interested in are `stat`, `statm` and `status`. The latter is more human-readable, whereas the former two give the same info in a more machine-readable format.

A starting point about how to interpret the content of those files is available in the `proc(5)` manpage.

Answer (score 0):

Other then keeping track of all your memory allocations I don't believe there is a way to calculate the heap size or usage

Answer (score 0):

Use `malloc_info()`.  Have fun with the XML aspect of it.  `mallinfo()` (as shown in another answer) does a similar thing but is restricted to 32-bit values... a foolish thing to rely on in 2010+.