# How to check how much memory has already been allocated by new()?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I'm trying to do this in C++:

```
int m1 = f(); // total memory allocated
void* p = new Foo();
int m2 = f(); // expect this to be larger than "m1"
```

I'm looking for a function that will return total amount of dynamic memory allocated by my process up to this very moment.

BTW, I'm not NOT on Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect programmatically count of bytes allocated by process on Heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696671/how-to-detect-programmatically-count-of-bytes-allocated-by-process-on-heap)

Comment: @kiner_shah it's close, but the examples provided in the answer you cited don't compile with gcc C++11. Could you please post here a complete example and I will will vote/select it?

Comment: I am not sure which example you tried - was it the selected best answer or the highest voted one? The highest voted one seems to not work for 64-bit systems (as per comment there).

Comment: @kiner_shah just post here the one that compiles and works for you, with gcc++11 :)

Comment: So I was looking into overloading new and delete operators, but it seems one of the overloads is not supported in GCC 11 (Overload number 5 and 6 in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) :-(